# How to multiply a tensor with a vector?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 2 tensors

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2])
b = torch.tensor([[[10,20],
                   [30,40]],
                  [[1,2],
                   [3,4]]])
```

and I would like to combine them in such a way that

```
a ? b = tensor([[[10,20],
                 [30,40]],
                [[ 2, 4],
                 [ 6, 8]]])
```

(and then sum over the 0th dimension, in the end I want to do a weighted sum)

I've tried:

```
""" no idea how to interpret that """
a @ b                                                                                                                                                                                                
tensor([[ 70, 100],
        [  7,  10]])

b @ a                                                                                                                                                                                                
tensor([[ 50, 110],
        [  5,  11]])

for i in range(b.size()[0]): # works but I don't think this will work with autograd 
      b[i] *= a[i] 

a * b              # multiplies right side by 2
tensor([[[10, 40],
         [30, 80]],

        [[ 1,  4],
         [ 3,  8]]])

a.unsqueeze(1)     # multiplies bottom side by 2
tensor([[[10, 20],
         [60, 80]],

        [[ 1,  2],
         [ 6,  8]]])

a.unsqueeze(2) * b # dimension out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work`c = a.unsqueeze(1).unsqueeze(1) * b`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try below code:

```
a = torch.tensor([1,2])
b = torch.tensor([[[10,20],
                   [30,40]],
                  [[1,2],
                   [3,4]]])

print((a.view(-1, 1)*torch.flatten(b, 1)).view(b.shape))
```

output:

```
tensor([[[10, 20],
         [30, 40]],

        [[ 2,  4],
         [ 6,  8]]])
```

Here, we are basically carrying out below steps:

- Reshaping `a` to a 2d tensor of size `[a.shape[0],1]`, i.e. `[2, 1]` in above case.
- Then, we are using `torch.flatten()` to flatten tensor `b` starting from the first dimension(i.e. `start_dim=1`). Here, `end_dim=-1` by default. Resultant size is `[2, 4]`.
- Performing element-wise multiplication.
- Finally, reshaping the result to shape same as original tensor `b`, i.e `[2, 2, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting -- I tried a few different broadcasting tricks and didn't see any obvious wins, so the simple version:

```
b[0] *= a[0]
b[1] *= a[1]
c = b
```